# Download multiple content asynchronously from a single coroutine

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Is it possible to download multiple content asynchronously using only a single coroutine? For example, I have an array of urls but I only can obtain this array from within a coroutine. Once I have the array, I would like to download the content for each url in the array but where all of them are done asynchronously:

```
withContext(appDispatchers.IO) {
    val Urls = getUrlsFromBackend()

    // Download the content for each url asynchronously

}
```

Comment: using a single coroutine? no. You can create a separate coroutine for each element and join them with the main coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create child coroutines. Each coroutine is a unit of concurrency, so you create one for each url.

```
withContext(appDispatchers.IO) {
    val Urls = getUrlsFromBackend()

    // Download the content for each url asynchronously
    val contents = Urls.map{ async { dowloadContent(it) } }.awaitAll()
    // Use contents
}
```